# form_for but to post to a different action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a `form_for @user`, but post to a custom action in the users controller.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 181):

```
form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'myaction')
```

or

```
form_for @user, :url => whatever_path
```

Comment: I dont think `url_for` is necessary. Also since controller is the same, you could use `form_for @user, :url => :action => 'myaction'`

Comment: Above answer was helpful but I had to tweak it a little as otherwise the POST was always routing to the edit controller action otherwise:            <%= form_for(@user, url: {action: "myaction"}, method: :post) do |user_form| %>. Please note that this is for a view file within the views/users/ folder.

Answer (score 42):

The following works for me:

```
form_for @user, :url => {:action => "YourActionName"}
```

Comment: This works. Check it out in the official docs by searching for `action:` (*action colon*) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Hmm not sure. I have put `form_for @user, url: {action: 'myaction'}` but it gives me `No route matches {:action=>"myaction", :controller=>"users"}` error.

Comment: @lulalala, of course, you must set routes as well.
in this case, like:
`resources :users do`
`collection do`
`get :myaction`
`end`
`end`

Answer (score 11):

I have done it like that

```
<%= form_for :user, url: {action: "update", params: {id: @user.id}} do |f| %>
```

Note the optional parameter `id` set to user instance id attribute.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass custom Controller to a form_for while rendering a partial form you can use this:

```
<%= render 'form', :locals => {:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'}%>
```

and then in the form partial use this local variable like this:

```
<%= form_for(:post, :url => url_for(:controller => locals[:controller], :action => locals[:action]), html: {class: ""} ) do |f| -%>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively the same can be reached using `form_tag` with the syntax:

```
form_tag({controller: "people", action: "search"}, method: "get", class: "nifty_form")
# => '<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/people/search" method="get" class="nifty_form">'
```

As described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#multiple-hashes-in-form-helper-calls

Comment: This it true, but the question asks to about a particular object - in this case `@user`. Using a `form_tag` will not bind the object's attributes to the form fields.

Answer (score 3):

new syntax

```
<%= form_for :user, url: custom_user_path, method: :post do |f|%>
<%end%>
```