# How to set the action with form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I created a new page on an existing controller.

I added 2 action methods on the controller: prompt_user and process_feedback.

So I get to the page via

```
redirect_to :controller => :users, :action => :prompt_user
```

And the form_for code looks like

```
<% form_for :user, @user do |f| %>
```

Which generates the following html

```
<form action="users/prompt_user" method="post">
```

Notice the action is prompt_user, where as I want to set it to process_feedback.  I thought I could change the action with a button

```
<%= submit_tag "Process feedback" %>
```

But that didn't work.

So my question is how can I change the action to process_feedback?

Also, as you can probably tell, I'm very new to rails, so if I'm doing something especially obtuse, I'd love to find out what it is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is from memory, but I think you can do something like this:

```
form_for :user, @user, :url => { :action => :prompt_user } do |f|
```

Comment: Btw, this is all available in the rails docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively the same can be reached using `form_tag` with the syntax:

See my answer on this question: here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37145293/1248725